# An almost Fresnel integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$So I tried doing the following integral:

$$I=\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(2^x)\,\d x,$$

which is quite similar to the famous [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).  First, I rewrote $\sin$ using its complex exponential definition, then I let $u=2^x$:

$$I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{i2^x}-e^{-i2^x}}{2i}\,\d x = \frac1{2i\ln(2)} \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{e^{iu}-e^{-iu}}u \,\d u.$$

(so close to letting me use Frullani's integral $\ddot\frown$)

But where do I go from here?  It looks very close to a place where I could use the exponential integral or something like that, but not quite...

Comment: Let $y = 2^x$ 
$$I = \frac{1}{\log(2)}\int^\infty_1 \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\,dy = \frac{1}{\log(2)} \left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\mathrm{Si}(1)\right)$$

Comment: Dang it!  And I just thought of that too!  $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Also we can use the other definition 

$$I =- \frac{\mathrm{si}(1)}{\log(2)}$$

where $$\mathrm{si}(x) = -\int^\infty_x \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\,dy$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Observe that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(2^x)\ dx =\frac{\pi }{2\ln 2}$$ with the same path given in my answer below.

Comment: @OliverOloa hm...I'm wondering about the convergence for that one.  Likewise, following the approach I attempted to use will allow Frullani's integral to solve that one quite nicely as well :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you. The above integral converges, since as $x \to -\infty$, we have $\displaystyle \sin (2^x) \sim \frac1{2^{|x|}}=e^{-|x|\ln 2}$.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't just [throw this into Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+of+sin(2%5Ex)+dx), get the answer, and then work backwards

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Nah, that's not as fun for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint**. One may perform the change of  variable
$$
u=2^x, \quad \ln x= \frac1{\ln 2}\cdot \ln u, \quad dx=\frac1{\ln 2}\cdot \frac{du}u,
$$ giving
$$
I=\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(2^x)\ dx=\frac1{\ln 2}\cdot\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}\ du=\frac1{\ln 2}\cdot\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\text{Si}(1)\right)
$$ where we have made use of the sine integral function [$\text{Si}(\cdot)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Though it is a bit strange that you use the word "Hint".

Comment: @projectilemotion Thank you. Maybe it's a habit saying all details are not provided ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you perform this change of variable:

$$y = 2^x \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x = \frac{\log(y)}{\log(2)}\\
dx = \frac{dy}{y \log(2)}\\
x = 0 \Rightarrow y = 1\\
x = +\infty \Rightarrow y = +\infty
\end{cases},$$

then you obtain the following:
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \sin(2^x)dx = \frac{1}{\log(2)} \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} dy = \frac{\text{Si}(+\infty) - \text{Si}(1)}{\log(2)},$$

where $\text{Si}(x)$ is the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral). I guess you can't do more than this.

Comment: Well, one may show that:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \operatorname*{Si}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$